# How do I set up a huge background image that never scales down nor produces scroll bars?

Tags: html, css, background-image, dreamweaver

I have a pretty big image (over 3k) that I want to set up as my homepage background.
The issue is that I want it to simply stick to the top left corner of the browser.

It should **only resize (proportionally) if the browser window is bigger than the image** and **never produce scroll bars** (unless the content demands them)

Basically the image should be simply cutoff whenever the browser window is smaller, which will happen 90% of the time.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: have you attempted anything?   If you post what you have - you will have a better chance of getting answers

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to what is done on about.me?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do it using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
body {background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1) top left no-repeat;}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
    body { background-size:cover; }
}
```

where the min-width matches the width of the original image (you can also add a min-height too)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/NvSSk/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">

        <!-- place your content here -->

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[Take a look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/isaacalves/zg623/5/)

Comment: Not what I was looking for. It still scales the image. Thanks anyway.